# To loop over an image folder and display all images using React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, image-processing

I have been battling this issue. I was able to do this using Javascript but couldn't implement it on React. This is the challenge.

In JS, I used this code:

```
images.forEach((img, idx) => {
    img.style.backgroundImage = `url(./images/${idx + 1}.jpg)`;
  });
```

--to iterate over the folder 'images' and display all images in sequence. The idea was to scroll the images horizontally (full JS code below at the end of this description). I have tried to do the same thing on React js but couldn't figure a way out. I'd tried the same code on JSX but didn't work. I needed a single line of code just as JS to iterate and display all images in React js. I would gladly appreciate your solution.

This is the full JS code:

```
    var images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".img")];
    var slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
    var sliderWidth;
    var imageWidth;
    var current = 0;
    var target = 0;
    var ease = 0.05;
    
   images.forEach((img, idx) => {
        img.style.backgroundImage = `url(./images/${idx + 1}.jpg)`;
      });
    
      function lerp(start, end, t) {
        return start * (1 - t) + end * t;
      }
    
      function setTransform(el, transform) {
        el.style.transform = transform;
      }
    
    
      function init() {
        sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        imageWidth = sliderWidth / images.length;
        document.body.style.height = `${
          sliderWidth - (window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight)
        }px`;
      }
      window.addEventListener("resize", init);
    
      function animate() {
        current = parseFloat(lerp(current, target, ease)).toFixed(2);
        target = window.scrollY;
        setTransform(slider, `translateX(-${current}px)`);
        animateImages();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
    
      function animateImages() {
        var ratio = current / imageWidth;
        var intersectionRatioValue;
    
        images.forEach((image, idx) => {
          intersectionRatioValue = ratio - idx * 0.7;
          setTransform(image, `translateX(${intersectionRatioValue * 70}px)`);
        });
      }
    
      init();
      animate();
```

How can I loop over the image folder and display all images using React js?

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests you're using React.

Comment: That's the question. The code above is JavaScript not React. I'm asking how to implement the above JS code in React.

Comment: Have you read the [introduction to React](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)? Or looked at any tutorials?

Comment: Yes, I have. Every solution, just as the arfi720 response below, points to a mapping solution but that is not what I'm looking for. With JS, I could easily loop through files in a folder and display them via HTML tag. I'd always find a solution in bringing JS, HTML, and CSS codes into React with little tweaks in JSX syntax but this one has been a pain in the neck. It made me realize how different React is from JS even though some JS codes work directly in React.

Comment: You need to import using require. Context and iterate image folder using map.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into too much of your code, I think what you are looking for is the map function and a structure something like this:

```
const Images = ({images}) => {
  
  const imageComponents = images.map((img, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <img src={img} alt=`Image number ${i}` />
      </div>
    )
  });

  return(
    <div>
      {images}
    <div>
  )
}
```

Basically use the map function on your array and return a component from each iteration (remember to include a unique `key` prop) and then return that array of components as part of your parent component (in my example, `Images`. You should be able to pop a lot of your js code into the same component or a parent of `Images`, depending on the functionality.

Comment: Can I iterate through a directory with React? That's precisely the question I'm asking. I'm trying to iterate through the images folder and return all the images one by one to the client to scroll horizontally. Is there a way to do this in react? The above JS code worked for HTML/CSS/JS but not React.

Comment: In the above example, I'm iterating through the value `images` which is passed as a prop to the component. This assumes that `images` is an array of paths to images. You should be able to construct this array however you are doing it in javascript.

Comment: This component does not have image list which should point to image folder. So answer is not correct or what a questioner is looking for.

Comment: Require. Context is solution as per react.

Answer (score 0):

we can use something like below,

//create a function importAll (or any name)

```js
  function importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);
  }

//call that iimportAll function
  const listOfImages = importAll(
    require.context(
      "path of the folder from which you want to extract files",
      false,
      /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/
    )
  );

NOTE: (png|jpe?g|svg) -- this is files format which you want to extract from the defined folder
```

read more about tech @ [www.capscode.in/blog](http://www.capscode.in/blog)

Comment: if you want to help please provide a more complete solution. Your code is using functions that are not standard from js or reactjs and you are not showing what it's looks like.

Comment: you just have to create a importAll function (or any name) and then call that function with JS require.context as a argument followed with the patch of the folder